# How to make another item in Navigation drawer?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, class, android-layout

I tried to create another item in the basic navigation drawer activity template based on the already existing ones. I set it up like the others but I get this error on the item/fragment I created.

cannot find symbol new ViewModelProvider(this).get(ProbaViewModel.class);

[image: the one on the left is one of the original fragments that comes with the template. The right is what I made]

I hope it's visible. It's funny because the line which is red was already red by default on the fragments that were already there but the app worked just fine. It has a problem with the one I made only. What could be the problem? I use the 4.3 version because that's required in my class.

```
public class ProbaFragment extends Fragment {
    public ProbaViewModel probaViewModel;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        probaViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(ProbaViewModel.class); // here

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_proba, container, false);
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_slideshow);
        probaViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });
        return root;
    }
}
```

Dependencies

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.proba2"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Comment: looks like you need an import. Seems ViewModelProvider is not recognized

Answer (score 0):

can you try to remove error import and resync your project and verify below import

```
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
```

As earlier shared gradle seems deprecated so remove that also.

Comment: Now I get this: Failed to resolve: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.4.0